# find and replace in xml file

Tags: xml, perl, awk, sed

I want to replace a specific value in xml file.

My Test XML is as below -

```
      <Field Name="ABC" IsArray="false" IsLocked="false">
    <Description>THIS IS FOR ABC VALUE</Description>
    <Comment></Comment>
    <PropertyList>
            <Property Name="ABC" Type="Boolean">
            <DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue>
            </Property>
    </PropertyList>
    <PropertyValueList>
            <PropertyValue PropertyName="ABC">
                    <Value>true</Value>
            </PropertyValue>
    </PropertyValueList>
</Field>
```

I want to change value from true to false only for `PropertyName=ABC`

Any suggestions?
sed/awk/perl anything would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this through awk,

```
awk '/PropertyName=\"ABC\"/{print; getline; sub(/true/,"false")}1' file
```

Comment: @user3780855 Its OK to ask someone accept an answer, but you should always wait some hour before accepting it, sine it may come a better one.

Comment: @Jotne he's a new user. So that i posted the above link. And also he mentioned "This answer works for me".

Comment: And it does not work, it removes the line `<Property Name="ABC" Type="Boolean">` you need `awk '/PropertyName=\"ABC\"/{print;getline; sub(/true/,"false")}1'`. You could write: If you like my answer and you do not find some better after some time, consider accepting it.

Comment: @jotne oh sorry. forget about that. I will follow the above.

Comment: And you should try to avoid using `getline`, look what `Ed` writes here: http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline  You could do: `awk '/PropertyName=\"ABC\"/{f=NR} NR=f+1{sub(/true/,"false")}1'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php):

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/Field/PropertyValueList/PropertyValue/Value/text()" -v "false" test.xml > result.xml
```